# How do you append corresponding lines in one file to corresponding lines of another file

Tags: text-processing

For example if I have file A:

```
s  
s  
s  
s  
s
```

And file B:

```
d  
d  
d  
d  
d
```

How do I make file C:

```
s d  
s d  
s d  
s d  
s d
```

I have been trying to use sed, awk, and xargs but to no success. I'm using bash on a mac.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interleave the lines of two or more files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140563/how-to-interleave-the-lines-of-two-or-more-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will `paste` work for you?

```
paste A B > C
```

It is extremely fast.

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
paste -d ' ' A B > C
```

or

```
pr -Tm -s' ' A B > C
```

You can remove the delimiter specifications (`-d ' '` and `-s' '` respectively) if you don't mind the default (tab) delimiters.